# Converting a list of strings that represent hex values into actual hex values

Tags: python, list, type-conversion, hex

So, I have a list containing strings that represent hex values like:

```
['02', 'ff', '98', '80', '39', '31', '03']
```

I would like to generate a new list that contains the actual hex values like:

```
[0x02, 0xff, 0x98, 0x80, 0x39, 0x31, 0x03]
```

Is there a way to do that?

If needed I can also get acces to the actual byte stream in the form of:

```
b'\x02\xff\x9c\x80D1\x03'
```

I need this "transformation" to perform bit-a-bit boolean operations on the elements of the list

Comment: What do you mean by 'actual hex values'? Hexadecimal is just a representation of an integer.

Comment: @LancelotduLac "actual hex" meaning a rapresentation of a byte into hex format as I will need to apply boolean operations to them. Maybe I explained myself not in the best way

Comment: @KellyBundy I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: The values in your list and your "actual byte stream" don't seem to match. What's up with that?

Comment: @NicoCaldo the best way to be unambigous is to speak in terms of the *type of object you want*. Your question implies you want the `int` objects with the corresponding hexadecimal values

Comment: @KellyBundy the OP says they want a `bytes` objects. Presumably to pass to something that expects a `bytes` object. If they want to work with a sequence of integer values, then yeah, just using `vals = [int(x, 16) for x in data]` would be better

Comment: @KellyBundy ah, you are right, i misread the last part. Yes, presumabbly the OP should just do `list(bytestream)` to get to the list of integers, not do an intermediate conversion to strings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert the hexadecimal string representations like this:

```
a = ['02', 'ff', '98', '80', '39', '31', '03']

b = [int(x, 16) for x in a]
```

This will create a list with integer equivalents of the input strings